# Push Local Notification when app is terminated

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

This is the Notification plugin initialization

```
onInit() async {
    log('=========> Init NotificationUtil');
    _notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    ///Configure timezone
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String? timeZoneName = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName!));

    ///Setup for plugin
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
    const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
    );
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await _notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {},
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse,
    );
    log('=========> Init FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin');
  }
```

I want to create a reminder feature which can be remind daily at a specific date time.So I create two function for test schedule and push with interval

```
onShowNotification() async {
    log('=========> onShowNotification');
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        notificationId, 'your channel name',
        channelDescription: 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await _notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      0,
      'title zonedSchedule',
      'body zonedSchedule',
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 2)),
      notificationDetails,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    );
  }

  onPeriodicallyScheduleShowNotification()async{
    log('=========> onScheduleShowNotification');
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        scheduleNotificationId, 'your channel name',
        channelDescription: 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await _notificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      0,
      'title every min',
      'body every min',
      RepeatInterval.everyMinute,
      notificationDetails,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
    );
  }
```

This works perfectly unless app is terminated. There is nothing happened when i built on real device and simulator.
I've thought i would use [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) to push notification on background service but i'm not sure with this concept

1.Try to excute push notification periodically and zonedSchedule
2.Do those when app is terminated
3.Try to apply workmanager

Answer (score -1):

In your main app, you can set a If, if your app is lauch by a push notifications, then you deploy your screen, or dialog, etc.

this is my example:

```
 Future<void> getNotificationAppLaunchDetails() async {
    notificationAppLaunchDetails = !kIsWeb && Platform.isLinux
        ? null
        : await localNotificationPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    // Verificamos si
    if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
      String? selectedNotificationPayload =
          notificationAppLaunchDetails!.notificationResponse?.payload;

      if (selectedNotificationPayload != null) {
        try {
          // LANZAS TU PANTALLA, O LO QUE SEA QUE QUIERAS, ESTE ES MI EJEMPLO:
          // Map messageMap = convertStringToMap(selectedNotificationPayload);
          // LocalPushModel remote = LocalPushModel.fromJson(messageMap);
          // navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(
          //   notificationPageRoute,
          //   arguments: remote,
          // );
        } catch (e) {
          log("ERROR: $e");
          print("ERROR: $e");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```